# How can I fetch records not doubled?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have three models such as `Community`, `Tagging`, and `Tag`

- Community `belongs_to :tag`
- Tagging `has_one :community` <= taggable_id will be Community's id
- Tagging `belongs_to :tag`
- Tag `has_many :taggings` # Tag has 'name' attribute

and this is my code

```
@communities = Community.joins(taggings: :tag).where(tags: { name: params[:tag] }).page(params[:page]).order("cached_votes_up DESC")
```

However, in the result page, it shows 2 of the same community records if the community had both "APPLE" and "apple" in tags.

How can I make it show only 1 record in result even when the community had the same tags both in lower case and upper case?

Comment: have you tried to add `.group('communities.id')` after the where?

Comment: @MrYoshiji could you please show the whole code how would it be?

Comment: `Community.joins(taggings: :tag).where(tags: { name: params[:tag] }).group('communities.id')` If using PostGreSQL, should raise an error about aggregate function

Comment: @MrYoshiji In MySQL, it won't work:(

Comment: Okay let's do the easy-but-not-best-way: `Community.joins(taggings: :tag).where(tags: { name: params[:tag] }).uniq`

Comment: @MrYoshiji It didn't work either.

Comment: @MrYoshiji do u have any idea to solve this?

Comment: No I have no idea. The one I sent you should work, if not it's because of your DB structure

Comment: @MrYoshiji Thanks. I use the gem called "acts_as_taggable_on" so I didn't make any model for `Tag` and `Tagging` :(

Comment: acts_as_taggable_on_steroid or acts_as_taggable ?

Comment: Is it possible to restrict uppercase and lowercase only to fetch 1 record?

Comment: it automatically fetch both uppercased and lowercased. That's the problem. How can I judge which one I'm using? Since I have both of them in my Gemfile. I cannot tell now:(

Comment: Remove the gem on_steroid, its old. Also you should add validations on your Tag name attribute, eventually a callback to set it to downcase at every save

Comment: @MrYoshiji Can we talk on chat a little bit please?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23647/discussion-between-mkk-and-mryoshiji)

Comment: can you discover models associations? I can't understand why you pass Community.joins(taggings) while Community just belongs_to :tag.

Comment: Hi can we talk on a chat?

Comment: @ValeryKvon It should be something like this `@communities = Community.joins(taggings: :tag).where('tags.name' = params[:tag] )`

Comment: If I did this. it does `like search` @communities = Community.joins(taggings: :tag).where('tags.name' => params[:tag] )

Comment: all I need is just complete match between tags.name and params[:tag]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I answered similar question. Are you same person?? Anyway this will work:

```
@communities = Community.joins(taggings: :tag).where(['binary(tags.name) = ?', params[:tag]]).page(params[:page]).order("cached_votes_up DESC")
```